# OpenCV circle/ellipse detection with blurred edge

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

How to locate the pupil(the small circle in the eyeball) in the following picture and calculate the area of the pupil. I tried Hough circle detection and ellipse fit on contours with various threshold but none of these naive approaches work very well.

Specifically, HoughCircle detection is totally lost in many noises, and Ellipse detection with pruning often end up giving the larger circle.

And I'm unsure how to determine a functional threshold without manual adjustment on a trackbar. Can somebody give me some guidance on how to accurately do this?

*Eyeball_sample*

[image]

Comment: Which circle is the the one you want to detect? Can you do this in multipe stages - first detect the boundary between iris and sclera, then by increasing the contrast within this circle/ellipse find sufficient colour differentiation to be able to pick out the pupil?

Comment: The darkest, smallest circle inside the eye, hope that makes sense... It is not always the case that the pupil is the darkest area in the image tho otherwise I could determine the threshold with a histogram

Comment: By curiosity, what is the thin black circular edge in the middle ?

Comment: This is a very challenging problem. The contrast between the pupil and the iris is small and the outline is not everywhere visible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not exactly sure what's the smallest thin black circular edge is.  You're right about the difference between iris and the pupil.

Comment: Detecting the iris is easy. You could try an active snake, starting from the iris outline.

Answer (score 1):

A simple image processing process should help you achieve your goal.

First load the image in grayscale. I think Otsu threshold method is robust enough to extract the pupil region of the eye. Extra morphological process is required to remove noise and unfilled regions

[image]

Then using a connected component analysis, we can isolate the pupil region for further processing.

[image]

With this region, we can get the edge by subtracting a dilated region with the original region as shown below.

[image]

Finally, we can run a circle fitting or a ellipse fitting algorithm to obtain the corresponding shape,

[image]

Circle fitting is shown in red wherelse ellipse is shown in green. Both return the same center position albeit slightly different shape.

Here is the code used. I shrink the image to speed up the process but it will work the same using the original size.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('eye.jpg',0)

small_img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),fx = 0.25, fy = 0.25)
r,c = small_img.shape
# Threshold objs
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(small_img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Morphological close process to cluster nearby objects
bin_img = cv2.dilate(thresh, None,iterations = 5)
bin_img = cv2.erode(bin_img, None,iterations = 5)

# Analyse connected components
num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(bin_img)

# Find circle center and radius
# Radius calculated by averaging the height and width of bounding box
bin_eye = np.zeros((r,c))
cnt_label = labels[r/2,c/2]
bin_eye[labels == cnt_label] = 255
area = stats[cnt_label][4]
radius = np.sqrt(area / np.pi)
cnt_pt = ((centroids[cnt_label][0]),(centroids[cnt_label][1]))

# fit ellipse
bin_eye_large = cv2.dilate(bin_eye, None,iterations = 1)

# Get ellipse edge
edge_eye = bin_eye_large - bin_eye

# extract location points for fitting
ellip_pts = np.where(edge_eye > 0)
ellip_pts = np.transpose(ellip_pts)
temp = np.copy(ellip_pts[:,0])
ellip_pts[:,0] = ellip_pts[:,1]
ellip_pts[:,1] = temp

# fit ellipse
ellip = cv2.fitEllipse(ellip_pts)


# Display final result
edges_color = cv2.cvtColor(small_img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.circle(edges_color,(int(cnt_pt[0]),int(cnt_pt[1])),int(radius),(0,0,255),1)
cv2.circle(edges_color,(int(cnt_pt[0]),int(cnt_pt[1])),5,(0,0,255),1)
cv2.ellipse(edges_color,ellip, (0,255,0))
cv2.circle(edges_color,(int(ellip[0][0]),int(ellip[0][1])),5,(0,255,0),1)

cv2.imshow('edges_color',edges_color)
cv2.imshow('bin_img',bin_img)
cv2.imshow('eye_label',bin_eye)
cv2.imshow('eye_edge',edge_eye)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: What you detected is the iris, not the pupil.